# Synaptics drives is not working correctly

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

When I start up Ubuntu, in the Mouse & Touchpad settings, the Touchpad is not shown. And the double-finger scroll as well as other gestures provided by synaptics driver will not work.

After execute:

> sudo rmmod psmouse
>
> sudo insmod /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/kernel/drivers/input/mouse/psmouse.ko

The option will show up.
How can I fix this?

---

I find that the psmouse module is loaded after boot (but not correctly, I will explain later). I have to run `sudo modprobe -r psmouse` and `sudo modprobe psmouse` to make the touchpad work in the right way.

I find that the original content of /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf is `options psmouse proto=imps`, and I that `proto=imps` option is not right for me. I am saying so because when I comment out that line and run  `sudo modprobe psmouse`, my touchpad will be all right, and if I don't, the touchpad option will not appear.

#### My guess is that at boot time, Ubuntu load the psmouse module with the `proto=imps` option for me. I wonder how to change that behavior?

---

I added the following lines to /etc/rc.local

`sudo rmmod psmouse`

`sudo modprobe psmouse`

And it's OK now, but I believe that this is not the best way. I still want to know why the module is not loaded right by the OS.

Comment: I think you should add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following lines to /etc/rc.local

sudo rmmod psmouse

sudo modprobe psmouse

And it's OK now, but I believe that this is not the best way.